# Do the maps $g$ and $g’$ define the same mathematical object?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, and powersets $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$. Further, let $f:A\to\mathcal{P}(B)$ be a map; and for any set $f(a)$, let $\mathcal{P}(f(a))$ be its powerset. Now,

1. Define a map $g:A\to \mathcal{P}(B)$ that satisfies $g(a)\in\mathcal{P}(f(a))$ for all $a\in A$.
2. Define a map $g’:\prod_{a\in A}a\to\prod_{a\in A}\mathcal{P}(f(a))$.

My question is: **is it true that $g\equiv g’$?** I am trying to figure out whether $g$ and $g’$ are equivalent definitions of the same mathematical object.

**EXAMPLE** [*addition following comments*]:

Consider the following example. Let $A\equiv\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B\equiv\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$. Further, let $f:A\to\mathcal{P}(B)$ to be such that $f(a_1)=\{b_1,b_3\}$ and $f(a_2)=\{b_2,b_3\}$.

Then, define $g:A\to\mathcal{P}(B)$ to be such that
\begin{gather}
g(a_1)=\{b_1,b_3\}\\
g(a_2)=\{b_2\}
\end{gather}

Then, define $g’:\prod_{a\in A}a\to\prod_{a\in A}\mathcal{P}(f(a))$ to be such that
\begin{gather}
g’(\{(a_1,a_2)\})=(\{b_1,b_3\},b_2)\\
\end{gather}

*Then, in a way, one can perhaps say that $g$ and $g’$ represent the same mathematical object, since for each $a\in A$, the restriction of $g’(\cdot)$ to $a$ coincides with $g(a)$ (i.e., $g(a)=g’_a(\cdot)$).*

Thank you all.

Comment: Oh, duh, right. My bad.

Comment: $g$ and $g’$ have different domains, so not sure how they could be equal. $g’$ has as a domain $A^{A},$ which, if $|A|>1,$ has greater cardinality than $|A|,$ so it is hard to see how they could be equal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have now added an example that may help clarify what I’m thinking of.

Comment: You can use the information provided by $g$ to determine what $g'$ is, and vice versa. If that's what you mean by defining the same object, then that holds.